# Regex for specific bbcode

Tags: php, regex

How to catch in PHP in the text with regex such a  bbcode
which has 2 possible  constructions at once

```
[gcountry allow="XX,YY"] Text Here [/gcountry]
[gcountry deny="AA,BB"] Text Here [/gcountry]
```

???

I need to find it, and regarding to IP address detect the country and replace the whole text with a Text Here if the country user comes from is an allowed one. The whole problem to  find out such bbcode and parsed to have allow and deny values also.

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: an array or several  variables where  I can see Allow or  Deny values  and  the Text Here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
\[gcountry (allow|deny)="([\s\S]*?)"\]([\s\S]*?)(?=\[\/gcountry\])
```

Capture group 1 contains the attribute name, `allow` or `deny`, 2 contains the value of the attribute, and 3 contains the text between the opening and closing tag.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vY6zQ1/2

Comment: he doest want to know the allow and deny , he want the text here

Comment: I need allow deny, but the text here too. How I need to modify your example to get the text itself too?

Comment: @MR.GEWA My mistake, forgot to capture one group, I've updated it, it now captures the inner text.